# mimemagic license issue on rails capistrano deploy

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-on-rails-6.1

Your bundle is locked to mimemagic (0.3.3), but that version could not be found
in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources,
that means the author of mimemagic (0.3.3) has removed it. You'll need to update
your bundle to a version other than mimemagic (0.3.3) that hasn't been removed
in order to install.

> rails 6.0.0
>
> mimemagic 0.3.10

Comment: The version of mimemagic that you want to use does not exist anymore. You need to update that gem to a later version. This is what the error message tells you. What is your question?

Comment: okay. even I have updated rails to 6.1.3.1 but the error still showed the same message.

Comment: not able to deploy the rails app. i am stuck here while deploying

Comment: How did you update to `6.1.3.1`? Do you have a reference to mimemagic in your Gemfile? Did you Gemfile.lock change after updating? Is mimemagic still in your Gemfile.lock?

Comment: Have you tried to update mimemagic using `bundle update mimemagick --conservative`? It seems that your Gemfile.lock wasn't updated.

Comment: thaks a lot. Issue is fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bundle update` but be aware that this update all your gems in the gemfile, maybe you are using mimemagic through rails dependency, and `bundle update mimemagic` not working for you. In that case, in my opinion `bundle update` is the best fit